# Facebook like button to summer cart products

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

How to add facebook like button to summer cart products, i mean for each product to have a like button.So yea you will tell php way or etc.. but i mean in summer cart, there is some kind of template system.

Answer (score 0):

Use it as other normal like button

in header:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
```

for each button:

```
<fb:like href="http://your.url/to/like" layout="box_count" show_faces="true" width="100" font="arial"></fb:like>
```

Comment: Man just read.. i need for each product different url, not i to put it, to be putted by himself

Answer (score 0):

See Summer Cart's demo. There is a [Facebook Like (Product) plugin](http://demo.summercart.com/admin/module.php?ModuleName=com.summercart.facebook_like).

Of course, it depends on the version you have. The demo is at 7.5.